# Jquery isNumeric for minus zero give true result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have validation for numeric values in my application but for value `"-0"` validation fail because.

```
$.isNumeric("-0")  => true
```

Comment: `-0` is a number. What did you expect?

Answer (score 2):

`-0` is numeric, according to the IEEE-754 standard governing the kind of numbers JavaScript uses. (In IEEE-754, `-0` and `0` are distinct values, though they're commonly treated as equal. `-0 === 0` is `true`, for instance, but recent versions of JavaScript have also included `Object.is`, where `Object.is(-0, 0)` is `false`.)

The functions `parseInt`, `parseFloat`, `Number`, etc. are all happy with `"-0"`, and it's a valid numeric literal in JavaScript as well.

If you want to disallow it, you'll need to add your own check for it.